# Published some content from staging slots and they appeared in production web database?

Tags: azure

I'm looking into this issue where I'm trying to understand how this event queue and publishing works with respect to shared master db with 2 CM Instances & respective 2 CD instances with dedicated web database.

I'm referring to this [blog post](https://www.robhabraken.nl/index.php/2683/the-staging-slot-eventqueue-issue/#comments)

Whereas according to [blog](http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/remote-events-how-to-investigate.html), respective CD's Event-Queue database table register corresponding CM instance details from where the request initiated.

I need help to understand how event-queue and publish queue is initiated from CM to CD. Have anyone came across this scenario. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: To add more details to this question for future reference. staging and prod slot -CMS has common master db whereas staging and prod CDs have dedicated web db. If we publish the content from staging it publishes the content in the production slot of web.

Comment: 1. Login to staging slot, make change and save it e.g. home page 
2. Open separate browser e.g. firefox and open prod slot
3. Clear cache using admin/cache
4. Make sure you can see the change in prod slot.
5. Then publish from staging slot.
6. Verify web prod and staging slot.[both slot reflects changes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: Leave the sitecore settings InstanceName empty in all cms staging and production instance. It will by default pick up the InstanceName +website name from IIS.
Below is the code that sitecore uses to get instance name:

```
string setting = GetSetting("InstanceName", null);
    if (!setting.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        return setting;
    }
    string machineName = MainUtil.GetMachineName(); // this function returns ((SystemInformation.ComputerName ?? Environment.MachineName) ?? string.Empty);
    try
    {
        string siteName = HostingEnvironment.SiteName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteName))
        {
            machineName = machineName + "-" + siteName;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return machineName;
}
```